# Random Values for an Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking for some help with my array. to put it in context im trying to create a console application that randomly generates a 4-digit code for the user to guess.

to do this I need an array of [3] and they need to have random numbers assigned to it.

```
        int[] secretCode = new int[3];

        secretCode[0] = 
        secretCode[1] = 
        secretCode[2] = 
        secretCode[3] =
```

My concern is what would i put here to make them generate random numbers?

thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Create an instance of the [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.random%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class and use Random.Next()

Comment: Does your array contain 3 or 4 items?  If 3, you need to remove `secretCode[3]`.  If 4, change the `new int[3]` to `new int[4]`.

Comment: If you have array of [3] you can only use indexes 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq and the [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] secretCode = 
    Enumerable.Repeat(0, 4).Select(i => rnd.Next(1000, 10000)).ToArray();
```

or more traditionally

```
int SIZE = 4;
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] secretCode = new int[SIZE]; 
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    secretCode[i] = rnd.Next(1000, 10000);
}
```

Note that there is a possibility of creating the same code more than once.  The solution assumes you want something in the range 1000..9999 (10000 is an *exclusive* upper bound) since the code is to be 4 digits.  If you would also allow smaller numbers, just adjust the Select portion.

As a side note, do not create a new instance of Random inside the select, as it would likely be reseeded to the same seed, based on the system time, resulting in the same "random" number over and over.  Also Random is fast, but not cryptographically strong.  If you need cryptographically valid randomness use [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) in place of Random.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I think I've worded the my question wrong, what I meant is that I need the program to randomly generate 4 separate integers between the values of 0-9, not one integer of a random value between 1000 and 10000.

Comment: You can change `rnd.Next(1000, 10000)` to `rnd.Next(0, 10)` and you should have what you need.